# Why does PHP PEAR report that it can't find some DLL's on Windows?

Tags: php, iis-6, pear

I'm trying to do a system wide install of PEAR on my web server. When I execute `go-pear.bat` in the PHP installation folder from the command line I get the following error windows popping up:

```
---------------------------
php.exe - Unable To Locate Component
---------------------------
This application has failed to start because php_mbstring.dll was not found. 
Re-installing the application may fix this problem. 

---------------------------
php.exe - Unable To Locate Component
---------------------------
This application has failed to start because php_pdo.dll was not found. 
Re-installing the application may fix this problem.
```

I also see the following warnings emitted in the command line window by the script:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/php_exif.dll' - The specified modul
e could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

All of these modules are configured in the `php.ini` file (which resides in the php install folder `c:\php`).

They are also reported correctly by `php_info()`.

I'm running PHP 5.2.6 Windows Non thread safe build on FastCGI on IIS6.

**Update:**

I've also tried (as suggested by [acrosman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079076/why-does-php-pear-report-that-it-cant-find-some-dlls-on-windows/1079152#1079152)) setting `extension_dir=c:\php` and `extension_dir=c:\php\ext` but without success.

I'm also remembering to kill the `php-cgi.exe` process (FastCGI keeps it alive) after each `php.ini` modification to force a re-read.

**Update 2:**

This looks like a PHP issue and not an issue with PEAR, running `php.exe` from the command line generates the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It turns out that `php.exe` needs to see the PHP extensions (`c:\php\ext`) folder in the system `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make you that the extension directory is properly set in you php.ini file.  I suspect that it's set as being a relative path, and that setting is causing problems when running from the command line:

```
extension_dir ="C:\PHP\ext"
```

Comment: That actually breaks things more because I think php appends ext/module.dll to that path.